# Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type

Tags: javascript, vite

when i run my vite project i get error on the console .
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

there is no other error

Comment: Look in the devtools Network tab. Your server is returning an error instead of your module code.

Comment: maybe lost file

Comment: when i enter the localhost i see in the terminal of vsCode that it redirects me throw al my folders

Comment: Did you ever get around this?

Answer (score 8):

Changing

```
vite build --base=./
```

to

```
vite build --base=/
```

solve my problem.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and managed to fix it.

By default Vite builds html with absolute asset references into the `dist` directory, because it assumes you deploy the `dist` folder to a root domain.

But if your project lives in a subdirectory like mine does, the absolute asset references won't work correctly.

Vite has a `base` config option that you can tweak to have it build relative assets urls. [Check the docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base).

```js
// vite.config.js
export default {
  base: './',
};
```

Or you can pass this config option when running the build command through the command line:

```bash
vite build --base=./
```

This works for Vite 4.3.9.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - the error is misleading - the server is not finding the index.html file.

Explanation below assumes you are deploying the public dist folder as a sub directory of the server folder.
Something like:

Project
|
+-- dist
|   |
|   +-- index.html
|   +-- assets
|   +-- |
|        +-- index-fb329e31.js
|        +-- index-ec6a2ce7.css
|
+-- index.html
+-- index.js

You have 3 modes of working with vite:

1. development where vite server serves the static files
2. development with built files - where your express server serves the static files
3. production with built files - where your express server serves the static files

##### Case 1: development, 2 ports

In this scenario you work with 2 ports - vite (5173 by default) and your express server (let's say its 3002). You have hmr & all that fun stuff.
Opening the browser on localhost:5173 goes to vite server. It knows how to load the correct static files.
Inside your app you have API calls that go to localhost:3002.

In your express file your write a handler for it:

```js
app.use('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('world'))
```

Everyone is happy :)

##### Case 2: development, 1 port

Now you want to build & test everything works before deploying to prod.
You need to run your app as you'd run it in prod - where the express server
is serving the static files.

- you build the client static files with *vite build*. This generates a dist folder with all the static assets & index.html file
- you run the server & run the app in the browser on localhost:3002

Now all requests go to the server, which wasn't the case before.
You need to point express to your static folder like so:

```js
// ++
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))
// ++
app.use('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('world'))
```

Note: the actual path depends on your folder structure, so you might need to modify this a bit

Now going to localhost:3002 will serve your index.html file
Everyone is happy :)

##### Case 3: production

This works very similarly to case 2, as here also the express server is serving all the files.

##### Bonus: API requests & client router

Once you add a client router to your application (e.g. /profile page), you will need to tell express that this should serve a static file and not search for a /profile endpoint.
Easiest way to do this is to prefix all api calls with something like /api,
and tell express that all other requests not starting with /api (like /profile) should return the index.html.

Example:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))
// ++
app.get(/^(?!\/api).\*/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(\_\_dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
})
// ++
app.use('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('world'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. For me what fixed it is my index.html elements that referred to the JS was using a leading / in front of 'assets'. I removed this to make it a relative path...

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="assets/index-cd561.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/index-cd561.css">
```

Maybe this will help someone, maybe, in the current landscape of npm builders, it won't help and it's some completely different error.

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same error, but the build was fine, just needed a hard refresh. Found this gem from the Vite docs after trying a bunch of this stuff...
[https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html][1]

> Vite emits vite:preloadError event when it fails
> to load dynamic imports. event.payload contains the original import
> error. If you call event.preventDefault(), the error will not be
> thrown.

```
window.addEventListener('vite:preloadError', (event) => {
    window.reload() // for example, refresh the page
})
```

> When a new deployment occurs, the hosting service may delete the
> assets from previous deployments. As a result, a user who visited your
> site before the new deployment might encounter an import error. This
> error happens because the assets running on that user's device are
> outdated and it tries to import the corresponding old chunk, which is
> deleted. This event is useful for addressing this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue on Firebase + React + Vite + ts and after trying all sorts of things I went to Chrome Incognito only to find it running perfectly there. Back on Chrome I just opened a new tab and it started showing up.