# Vue 3 + Vite, static inclusion of HTML that references a JS script in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, vite

I am trying to include some external HTML with JS script into my project. For simplicity, I would like to handle it as a static assets and load it into an iframe.

The template in my component shows how I reference it with an absolute path:

```
<template>
  <iframe class="h-full w-full" :src="`/external/file.html`"></iframe>
</template>
```

Now, under my public folder at the root of my Vue 3 + Vite project, I store this file:

```
public/
     external/
          file.html 
          script.js
```

That HTML file references the JS script that is in the same folder with a relative path:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
```

This works fine when in development mode, but fails when building and serving with a simple HTTP server. I get a MIME type error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Also, when I inspect the elements the iframe is filled with my `index.html`, instead of with `external/file.html`, potentially due to some fall back mechanism.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that's much appreciated, thanks.

I tried different ways of importing.

Comment: does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433591/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75433591/failed-to-load-module-script-expected-a-javascript-module-script-but-the-server)